# Google Play Services and MobileFirst 7.0 application

Tags: android, gradle, ibm-mobilefirst, dex

I am building a hybrid application using MobileFirst 7.0.
Here's the issue I'm encountering. In Android, I need to use Google native maps. As soon as I include the Google Play services library, I overrun the 65,536 limit and run into the multi-dex issue.

Since the solution requires Gradle builds, I am in a dilemma if I need to abandon MobileFirst facilities and switch to a Gradle build.
I read in other posts that Gradle is not supported in MobileFirst.

Is there any other way of accomplishing this without having to leave MobileFirst studio completely?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle support is indeed not yet part of Hybrid applications in IBM MobileFirst . However Gradle is no the only option, as documented by Google: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#multidex

There is this second option: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res

And you can also enable ProGuard which should help with this as well: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/c_pg_obfus_intro.html